# Are functions in contracts visible to everyone who has the block chain?

Tags: security

I have an experience with back end development and I am just getting started with Etherium, but I am a bit confused about something.

In Back End development, we mostly assume (if everything goes right) that the user has no way of seeing the actual code being run (So its kept proprietary). I might expose an endpoint to the user to request my service, but they have no way of actually seeing the code being run by me.

However, I've read that everything on the Etherium block chain is public, so I am a bit confused about how you would keep your code proprietary?

For example, suppose I implemented an image recognition service in solidity, where I receive and image and return the type of image to the user. What prevents a user who has my block chain to look at my code, copy it, and make a new block entry of his own with my code in it?

Comment: They are compiled to bytecode/opcode and broadcasted to network there not exactly readable unless you publish the source yourself.

Comment: Wait, so no one actually has the actual contract except me (the author)? In other words, I just compile my byte code and put it on the block chain?

Comment: Yes, unless you publish the contract code yourself. But decentralised applications are meant to be opensource and transparent or you have to get your code audited by a trusted service.

Comment: Bytecode can be reversed, so you should probably consider your code public. In any case, you would never perform something as computationally expensive as image recognition on the blockchain. Just submitting an image to the smart contract would be a significant expense, let alone performing an image recognition task. So you would do recognition off-chain, where you can certainly keep your code proprietary.